# Can I run some mod_wsgi apps on Python 2.7, and keep the rest on Python 2.5?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualenv

App A is written in Python 2.5 with Django and runs on an Apache server via mod_wsgi.
App B is written in Python 2.7 and I want it to run side-by-side on the same server.

I don't want to update App A to use 2.7, or change App B to use 2.5.

The question:

> Can I run two Django apps with two separate Python runtimes side-by-side on one Apache server?
>   If I can, how do I set this up?

This confuses the hell out of me because WSGI documentation [offers a Python “home” setting](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome) while [this document](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments) says `mod_wsgi` has to be compiled for a specific version of Python:

> Note that the version of Python from which this baseline environment is created must be the same version of Python that mod_wsgi was compiled for. It is not possible to mix environments based on different major/minor versions of Python.

Does it mean I can't have 2.5 and 2.7 Django apps running side by side?

Comment: "recompile mod_wsgi to use it with a different version of Python. We can't afford the server to go offline"?  How do those have anything to do with each other?  Can you explain how a recompile and `apachectl -k restart` will make the server go "offline"?

Comment: What I meant is if there are any incompatibilities, we don't existing apps to stop working. And we want to keep 2.5 for them.

Comment: We can't have two different mod_wsgi's, right?

Comment: Are you saying you have no test or staging environment?

Comment: Staging environment uses Python 2.7 from the beginning so it wasn't a problem. Also, we're not a software company, just a bunch of dudes making a startup so best practices weren't followed all the way.

Comment: "best practices weren't followed"... History doesn't matter.  Are you saying you have a staging environment and it uses 2.7 and everything works?  What -- exactly -- are you saying?

Comment: A comment with status ("Please see the edit") is useless.  Are you saying you have 2.5 code on a staging server running 2.7 and you want to know if the 2.5 code (running under 2.7) will also run in production under 2.7?  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. Two servers. Staging is 2.7. Production is 2.5. All older apps only use 2.5 features so they run on both servers without issues. New app uses 2.7 features so it only runs on staging server, and fails in production. I want to sandbox the new app to use 2.7 in production, while the rest of production should still be using 2.5.

Comment: I'll ask again.  Does ALL the production code work in staging under Python 2.7?  You said it did.  Then you said other stuff.  Please help me by (1) focusing on my failures to understand and (2) updating the question yet again to be really, really complete.  If everything runs in staging under 2.7, please clearly say that.  If something does not run in staging under 2.7, please clearly say that.

Comment: There are several **old** apps. All of the **old** apps are written in Python 2.5 (i.e., do no use any newer language features). Thus they are able to run fine both on production server (default runtime is Python 2.5) and the staging server (default runtime is 2.7). Now, the **new** app is using some of the 2.7 features. It can't run on production server (default runtime is 2.5). I'm moving the **new** app from staging to production.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you.  "If everything runs in staging under 2.7, please clearly say that" seems to be difficult.  It would be nice to know if everything runs in staging under 2.7.  But you seem unable or unwilling to provide this fact.   Without this information I cannot provide additional help.  Sorry.

Comment: Eek! I see your point now. If everything ran under 2.7, we would be able to just upgrade Python in prod. Unfortunately, staging server is only used for a couple of apps, so we can't really test. Yeah, it's messy. **The answer: we don't know if the old apps will survive 2.7 transition, and we're not ready to test. The question is about whether *sandboxing a single application to use 2.7* is possible**. Thanks for your time and sorry for the frustration I caused.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4448/discussion-between-dan-abramov-and-s-lott)

Comment: "so we can't really test".   Consider that testing is more important than any other thing you're doing.  Really.  If you consider testing as the single most important thing, you'll find that this problem (and perhaps others) go away.  Also consider that the time you spend working around a potential problem is often less than the time spent testing to see if the problem is even real.

Comment: Ridiculous. Did you leave those five comments just to mock me? Do you realize [there *are* cases when setting up proper staging is *more* costly than having issues like this occur once in a while](http://bit.ly/n6IK8I)?  Your last comment has about *nothing* to do with the question I asked. I didn't ask your opinion on importance of testing, my question is about sandboxing Python 2.7 environment, and it's you who seems to be completely unwilling to answer. It's the first time I leave such personal comment, and you should probably flag it to make the world a better place. Thanks.

Comment: After reading through this, I would recommend taking all your old 2.5 apps that are on production and **backport them to staging first.** This will clearly answer the question "will production survive an upgrade to 2.7?" (which you should plan to do anyway, even if it will just be a stepping stone to eventual migration to 3.x). And since it's staging, you can take all the time you need fixing things. Then when everything is verified on 2.7 on staging, you can push production to 2.7 and patch in whatever changes were needed to the old apps. Then you're on all-2.7 and done.

Comment: @Mike: I'll certainly do (and I just backported the new app). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, you 'can't have 2.5 and 2.7 Django apps running side by side'. It is not possible. The best you can do is have applications running in different virtual environments but where all virtual environments are for the same Python version as mod_wsgi was compiled for.